# Why typeof undefined is return string?

Tags: javascript, undefined

When I run from the browser

```
typeof undefined
```

I got `"undefined"` string. That is why? Most of the time I check my variable something like

```
if (a == 'undefined') {
  do something
}
```

is I am checking my variable a is equal to undefined? I don't understand about that. Can someone explain me? Another way to check undefined in javascript?

Comment: Do it this way -> `if(typeof a === 'undefined'){<...>}`

Comment: `typeof` returns the **name** of the datatype of the value (more or less). And the names are represented as strings.

Comment: Any other way to check undefined?

Comment: You can also compare the value against `undefined`. E.g. `v === undefined`, `v === void 0`, `v == null` (Catches undefined and null).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that is how `typeof`  works:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

```
if (a == undefined) { // instead its a type comparison
```

Answer (score 1):

`typeof` get's you the type as a string.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Answer (score 0):

`undefined` just happens to be a global name that holds [the undefined value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined).

Quoting the linked page,

> undefined is a property of the global object, i.e. it is a variable in global scope.
>   The initial value of undefined is the primitive value undefined.

`typeof` always returns a string describing the value of the name passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

The `typeof` operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand.

It changes like this

```
Undefined   :"undefined"
Null    :"object"
Boolean :"boolean"
Number  "number"
String  :"string"
Host object (provided by the JS environment)    :Implementation-dependent
Function object (implements [[Call]] in ECMA-262 terms):    "function"
Any other object    :"object"
```

[DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)